# How to push the table value into single array using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I need one help. I need to push single row table value into array using PHP and MySQL. I am explaining my table below.

> db_tc

```
id  tc1  tc2  tc3   tc4   tc5  tc6  tc7  tc8  tc9  tc10

 1  aa    bb   cc    dd   ee   ff   gg    hh      jj
```

Here I need need to push all column value to single array and using same key name. I am explaining my code below.

```
$faqquery="select * from db_tc order by id desc limit 1";
$faqdata= $this->modl_obj->db_get_data($faqquery);
$ctr=count($faqdata);
$tcArr=array();
if($ctr >0){
    foreach ($faqdata as $v) {

    }
}
```

Here which column has blank data that will not push into array. My expected output should like below.

```
$tcArr=[{'tc':'aa'},{'tc':'bb'},{'tc':'cc'},{'tc':'dd'},{'tc':'ee'},{'tc':'ff'},{'tc':'gg'},{'tc':'hh'},{'tc':'jj'}]
```

Please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: As a note, a schema like this with 10 columns for `tc` data violates the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) of 
[database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). A proper relational structure would be easier to deal with, you'd insert one record for each element of `$tcArr`.

Comment: I am little bit confused with your question ,Pleas explain properly  what you need Array or Array of arrays or Array of objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$faqquery="select * from db_tc order by id desc limit 1";
$faqdata= $this->modl_obj->db_get_data($faqquery);
$ctr=count($faqdata);
$tcArr=array();
if($ctr >0){
    $row = $faqdata[0];
    foreach ($row as $k => $v) {
        if($v && $k != 'id') {
            $tcArr[] = ['tc' => $v];
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Its `['tc' => $v];` or `['tc' => $v['column_name']];`. Please check.

Comment: It depends how your $faqdata array looks like. $v should be a value of field and $k should be column name - you can check if $k != 'id'

Comment: I have already given the table structure.my `$faqdata` array data look like `[{'key':'value'}]`.

Comment: I know the table structure but $faqdata structure depends on how your db_get_data function works - If it is an array of rows (as mysql_fetch_array func.) as I have assumed than in my code, i get the first row ($row = $faqdata[0];) and iterate over it's fields where the key is column name and the value is the column value.
If it works like mysql_fetch_row - you should ommit $row = $faqdata[0]; and iterate over faqdata fields not the $row.

Comment: No,expected output not coming.

Comment: Please dump your $faqdata

Comment: Please check `Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [tc1] => aa [tc2] => bb [tc3] => cc [tc4] =>dd [tc5] => ee [tc6] =>ff[tc7]gg [tc8] =>hh[tc9] =>  [tc10] =>jj ) )
`

Comment: I have rolled back my last update - don't you get the expected output? Can you show the difference?

Comment: This type `Array ( [0] => Array ( [tc] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [tc] => aa ) [2] => Array ( [tc] => bb ) [3] => Array ( [tc] =>cc) [4] => Array ( [tc] =>dd ) [5] => Array ( [tc] => ee ) [6] => Array ( [tc] => ff ) [7] => Array ( [tc] =>gg ) [8] => Array ( [tc] => hh ) [9] => Array ( [tc] =>  )[10]=>array(jj) )` is coming.

Comment: You expect JSON format and you are dumping in some other way - please show the result of json_encode($tcArr);

Comment: Yes,coming as per expected but why this `{"tc":"1"}` is there.

Answer (score 1):

As @tadman said, you should consider changing the schema for the table. But as an solution for your question instead (I will only write the `foreach`).

```
foreach($faqdata as $key => $value){
    if(strpos($key, "tc") !== FALSE){
        $tcArr[] = [preg_replace('/\d+/u', '', $key) => $value]; //preg_replace to remove the numbers that you do not wanted in your expected output.
    }
}
```

I haven't tested this code, and it may also varies a bit based on the MySQL output format you have, like object or array. Let me know and I will edit based on it.

EDIT: 
Even though I highly recommend you to change the schema of your table!

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($faqdata as $key=>$value) {
     if (($key!='id') && ($value!='') {
     $outputarray[]="{'tc':'$value'}";
     } 
}
$output=implode(',',$outputarray);
$output='['.$output.']';
```

Comment: Please check my post again.